# Java Cookie - expires date is returning in CST timezone from java / weblogic 12c

Tags: java, cookies, weblogic, internet-explorer-11, setcookie

I am using the following code to expire a cookie in a J2ee web application (java 8, weblogic 12c).

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("dgv", "");
cookie.setValue("");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Looking at the reponse, the expires header is in the CST timezone. This is preventing IE11 from deleting that cookie since it expects dates in the GMT timezone. We are only experiencing this on our production environment. Our non prod environments return dates in GMT. Where settings can i verify? Server date is in EST.

Here is what i see in the browser:

```
Set-Cookie: dgv=; domain=something.org; expires=Wed, 31-Dec-1969 19:00:00 CST; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure
```

Comment: Please quote the headers.

Comment: Why set max-age to zero? I wonder if that contributes to your problem.

Comment: @BasilBourque - setting maxAge to 0 is how the cookie is expired.

Comment: Is the expires header in CST timezone only in IE or also CST in other browsers? You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620172/expires-string-in-cookie-header) about setting expire cookie header in java.

Comment: @YuZhou - its on all browsers but everyone except IE11 is handling it fine. This happens only on our prod environment. In other enviroments, GMT time is being returned.

Comment: Are you certain there really are hyphens between your day, month, and year? Did you copy that sample header directly, or did you type it with possible typos introduced?

Comment: @BasilBourque I copied that directly from the browser

Answer (score 3):

In the past I've seen timezone issues with WebLogic starting with the incorrect default TimeZone. An easy way to check this is to print to logs the result of

```
ZoneId.systemDefault()
```

And see if it gives you CST or GMT. If it's wrong you can either programmatically change it or pass an environment variable

```
-Duser.timezone
```

possibly in the startWebLogic.sh(cmd) script

Worth checking the Timezone / date settings of the actual server WebLogic is installed on too.

Comment: Setting user.timezone will cause the server logs to start writing in gmt too right? We want that to continue writing in EST

Comment: Sever time is in EST

Comment: @user1187958 Tip: Logging should really be done in UTC. Sysadmins and programmers should learn to think in UTC while on-the-job. Focusing on UTC in logging, debugging, storing, and exchanging moments is much less prone to errors, confusion, and ambiguity.